# Как в PyQt6 получить доступ к функции, которая находится в другом модуле

Tags: python, ооп, классы, pyqt, pyqt6

Данный минимальный пример показывает, как с помощью переключения радио кнопок делать активацию/деактивацию спинбоксов.

Со временем код разрастается и требуется декомпозиция.

Помогите перенести методы `spinBoxSetEnabled_1()` и `spinBoxSetEnabled_2()` в отдельный файл.

**main.py**

```py
import sys

from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication
from PyQt6.uic import loadUi


class New(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(New, self).__init__()
        loadUi("Test.ui", self)

        self.RB_1.setChecked(True)
        self.RB_1.clicked.connect(self.spinBoxSetEnabled_1)
        self.SB_1.setEnabled(True)

        self.RB_2.setChecked(False)
        self.RB_2.clicked.connect(self.spinBoxSetEnabled_2)

    def spinBoxSetEnabled_1(self):
        self.SB_1.setEnabled(True)
        self.SB_2.setEnabled(False)

    def spinBoxSetEnabled_2(self):
        self.SB_1.setEnabled(False)
        self.SB_2.setEnabled(True)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = New()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

**Test.ui**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>732</width>
    <height>539</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <widget class="QGroupBox" name="groupBox">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>10</x>
      <y>0</y>
      <width>701</width>
      <height>491</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="title">
     <string>GroupBox</string>
    </property>
    <widget class="QSpinBox" name="SB_1">
     <property name="enabled">
      <bool>false</bool>
     </property>
     <property name="geometry">
      <rect>
       <x>40</x>
       <y>40</y>
       <width>131</width>
       <height>61</height>
      </rect>
     </property>
    </widget>
    <widget class="QSpinBox" name="SB_2">
     <property name="enabled">
      <bool>false</bool>
     </property>
     <property name="geometry">
      <rect>
       <x>200</x>
       <y>40</y>
       <width>131</width>
       <height>61</height>
      </rect>
     </property>
    </widget>
    <widget class="QRadioButton" name="RB_1">
     <property name="geometry">
      <rect>
       <x>50</x>
       <y>160</y>
       <width>95</width>
       <height>20</height>
      </rect>
     </property>
     <property name="text">
      <string>1</string>
     </property>
    </widget>
    <widget class="QRadioButton" name="RB_2">
     <property name="geometry">
      <rect>
       <x>210</x>
       <y>160</y>
       <width>95</width>
       <height>20</height>
      </rect>
     </property>
     <property name="text">
      <string>2</string>
     </property>
    </widget>
   </widget>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>732</width>
     <height>26</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как вариант:

**main.py**

```
import sys
'''
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication
from PyQt6.uic import loadUi
'''
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication 
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi

from q1514951_spinBox import SpinBoxs                             # !!! +++


class New(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(New, self).__init__()
        loadUi("q1514951_test.ui", self)                       # установите ваш
        
        self.spinBoxs = SpinBoxs(self)                            # !!! +++

        self.RB_1.setChecked(True)
# ------------------------------> vvvvvvvvvvvvv <------------------------------        
        self.RB_1.clicked.connect(self.spinBoxs.spinBoxSetEnabled_1)
        self.SB_1.setEnabled(True)

        self.RB_2.setChecked(False)
# ------------------------------> vvvvvvvvvvvvv <------------------------------         
        self.RB_2.clicked.connect(self.spinBoxs.spinBoxSetEnabled_2)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = New()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

**q1514951_spinBox.py**

```
# установите ваши импорты
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget


class SpinBoxs(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(SpinBoxs, self).__init__(parent)
        
    def spinBoxSetEnabled_1(self):
        self.window().SB_1.setEnabled(True)
        self.window().SB_2.setEnabled(False)
        print(f'Hello SB_1') 

    def spinBoxSetEnabled_2(self):
        self.window().SB_1.setEnabled(False)
        self.window().SB_2.setEnabled(True)        
        print(f'Hello SB_2')
```

**q1514951_test.ui**

```
# без изменений
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]